How to create a Specification that would match data from Postgres varchar[]
I have a set of filter values that come in as List<String> filters. They are matched against a varchar()[] in the postgres database. I am trying to create a org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification that could be used to search in the required column.
Is there a way to create such a specification, that would work?
The not-working piece of code is attached
private Specification<DatabaseTable> hasFilters(
      List<String> filters) {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
      Predicate filterPredicate = cb.disjunction();

      if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(filters)) {
        for (String filter : filters) {
          filterPredicate = cb.isNotNull(
              cb.function("array_position", Integer.class, root.get("columnName"),
                  cb.literal(filter))
          );
        }

      }
      return filterPredicate;
    };
  }

The idea here is to use postgres function 'array_position' to search for strings inside the array and see if they have a position in the array. And if the value has the position, I would match it with cb.isNotNull But in the end, it just doesn't work, the returned values are not filtered. Any ideas or suggestions would be very helpful.
